# Train, save model and load: error while loading model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm training a model using TensorFlow and Keras. I would like to save the model and then load it. but I'm getting some errors.

I compile the model this way:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=adam,
              metrics=['accuracy', top3, top5])
```

and after training I'm loading the model this way:

```
model.save('model')
```

So I get a folder "model" containing:

```
---model 
     ---assets
     ---variables
     ---keras_metadata.pb
     ---saved_model.pb
```

Finally, I try to load the model using:

```
import tensorflow as tf

new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model')
new_model.summary()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Unable to restore custom object of type _tf_keras_metric 
currently. Please make sure that the layer implements `get_config`and 
`from_config` when saving. In addition, please use the `custom_objects` 
arg when calling `load_model()`.
```

Comment: Try to save like this: ``model.save('model.h5')``

Comment: I tried that too. I got: OSError: Unable to open file (bad object header version number) when doing: new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')

Comment: I think this error is due to your custom metrics.

Answer (score 1):

When your model utilizes custom objects, such as your custom metrics, you have to specify them with the `custom_objects` argument of `load_model`:

```py
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model', custom_objects={'top3': top3, 'top5': top5})
```

Note that the definitions of your custom metrics must be available in the same module/environment you are loading the model.

Comment: @Laura did the answer resolve your problem?